# Delphi Component Runtime Creation

Tags: delphi, components

I am creating a component at runtime but i am having an issue because when I create 2 of these components, I would change the value of the properties on one of them but it seems to also change it on the other.

How can I create components at runtime so they are seperate components and not instances of eachother?

Ok so this is the code I am using to create the component.

```
Cell[CellCount]:= TBattery.Create(nil);   
Cell[CellCount].Top := Random(500);    
Cell[CellCount].Left := Random(500);   
Cell[CellCount].Parent := Self;   
Cell[CellCount].ID := CellCount;   
CellCount := CellCount + 1;
```

I am using the GDI graphics to draw lines between multiple instances of TBattery. The problem I am having is; if I create two components then add a third, when I move the third one the lines get drawn to that one instead of sticking to the second component.

I uploaded my source files, I'm sure a lot of it won't make sense and my implementation may be bad but any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

http://pastebin.com/8WUkT1rw

http://pastebin.com/BpASvc7N

They are both part of a electrical circuit simulator for my school project if that helps understanding what the code is for :s

Comment: The shown code creates only one. Is it in a loop? It's better if you include all the relevant code in your question, including the Cell array declaration. On the other hand, it may be a bug in the TBattery class, is that class developed by you?

Comment: Please show enough code for us to reproduce your problem. Don't be shy!

Comment: Why is this tagged as C when it does not appear to have anything to do with the C language?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to tag it with C, the TBattery class is a class made by me using a frame. I'll edit it with more relevant code, but theres quite a lot of stuff connected to it :s

Comment: There's far too much code. And it's offsite. And you did't say what it's meant to do, and how it fails. Please simplify and add clarity. fWIW, I don't like those global variables.

Comment: First you'll have to determine that you are indeed looking at separate instances. Keep track of the Addr(Cell[CellCount]) to see if the pointer addresses match.

Comment: The problem is, if I have lets say two TBATTERY created. I want to know how to retrieve the CELL.TOP (Y cordinate) value of both of them, if I click on one of the components then store the .TOP value and then click on the other component, my first stored .TOP value becomes the second one, seemingly because they are separate components at runtime?

Not sure if that makes sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

A simple runtime component creation is...

first create a unit
second create a procedure 
ex

```
procedure Label_Comp(Location: TWinControl; Text: String; Label_Left,Label_Top,Numofcomp: Integer; NameOwn: string; Label_Autosize,Label_FontBold,Label_Trans: Boolean);
```

add in var

```
var
 MyLabel: TsLabel;
```

and then the procedure code

```
procedure Label_Comp(Location: TWinControl; Text: String;            
  Label_Left,Label_Top,Numofcomp: Integer; NameOwn: string;                                                               
  Label_Autosize,Label_FontBold,Label_Trans: Boolean);
begin
 MyLabel := TLabel.Create(main);
 MyLabel.Name := 'Label' + NameOwn + IntToStr(Numofcomp);
 MyLabel.Parent := Location;
 MyLabel.Caption := Text;
 MyLabel.Left := Label_Left;
 MyLabel.Top := Label_Top;
 MyLabel.Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
 MyLabel.Font.Size := 8;
 MyLabel.Font.Color := clWindowText;
 MyLabel.AutoSize := Label_Autosize;
 if Label_FontBold = True then
   MyLabel.Font.Style := MyLabel.Font.Style + [fsBold];
 MyLabel.Transparent := Label_Trans;
 MyLabel.Visible := True;
end;
```

and call it from your program as you want
ex

```
for i := 0 to 10 do 
 Label_Comp(main.panelBattery,'Exit',90,24,i,'',True,True,True);
```

The problem here is to remember the i statement...

I hope i help...